# Can't run texlive 2015 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu

I downloaded texlive 2015 from the Tex Users Group web and successfully installed. After installation I added these lines in my .bashrc:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

However when I try to run it I get:

```
~$ latex
The program LaTeX is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

Same using `latex --version`.

This is a clean installation on a x64 Ubuntu 14.04 system. I have successfully installed latex 2013 (and previous versions) before in other machines just with ./install-tl and setting the PATH. Any idea what could be the problem?

**Edit:**

`echo $PATH` gives me:

```
/home/jaime/science/Ureka/variants/common/bin:/home/jaime/science/Ureka/bin:/home
/jaime/science/Ureka/python/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr
/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr
/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you've actually added it to the path: what does for example `echo $PATH` or `command -v latex` give?

Comment: I'll edit my question with the output from `echo $PATH`. No results for `command -v latex`

Comment: Case matters, you are exporting path in lower case. Also, move this to dot profile, log out and in again. It does not belong in bashrc (will give you headache later on). Btw: are you using standard Ubuntu, no switch to exotic shells?

Comment: As observed, you want `x86_64` in those paths, not `x68_64`

Comment: @JosephWright could have been days and I still would not see it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @daleif lower case was just a typo but thanks for noticing. I'm not saying that you are wrong, but I've always done it on .bashrc since I could not make it work doing it on .profile (since ubuntu 10 or so)

Comment: @JVR For what it's worth, not long ago (couple months?) I installed TeX Live 2015 on Ubuntu 14.04 following [this set of instructions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/46980). It includes guidelines for PATH as well. Progbably you've seen that already, but mention it "just in case". Working a treat for me.

Comment: @JVR you are fine if you start everything through a commandline (I almost always do that). But say you start TeXmaker from a menu, then if PATH is set in `.bashrc` then that shell is never used and TeXmaker cannot call LaTeX, that is why is it better to recommend adding it to `.profile` then it works in all cases.

Comment: You PATH looks fine now. Does `which latex` give any results?

Comment: @daleif ok thanks for that info, I'll give it a try again with .profile. Latex is working now, it was just a typo in the PATH, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your .bashrc is correct. Try reading this post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) on how to do it.

In particular your PATH variable should be set like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux
```

without the semicolon at the end. You also don't need to export.

I believe you have made a typo in your post. It should be **x86_64-linux** and not x68_64-linux as you have written!

After doing that, don't forget to open a new shell before you test if it worked.

Comment: I did as you suggested but same result. Also read the post and tried to do it in .profile but still same result

Comment: Yes, the x68_64-linux was the problem as other user also suggested. Thanks!